# Universal Windows Platform Page KeepAlive

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

In Universal Windows Platform is there a way to keep page alive? So let’s say I am entering a new customer and at some point I realised that the category I want to assign has not been created, so I want to navigate to a different page to add that category but I don’t want the current page to be destroyed and loose the data. In WPF this scenario is very simple with PRISM KeepAlive.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache a page and it's content by setting the `NavigationCacheMode` property. The default setting of this property is `Disabled`, so you have to set it manually in your constructor:

```
public MyPage()
{
    // The page will only be cached,
    // if the cache size of the parent Frame is large enough for this page
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;

    // The page will always be cached,
    // even if it exceeds the cache size of the parent Frame
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
}
```

For further details, look into the [Quickstart: Navigating between pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh771188.aspx) topic on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll check it tonight :)